# accessing forloop.counter within custom template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I wrote a custom template tag get_item, which takes an index and returns the item in a session-held list of that index. My problem is that it seems I can't access forloop.counter within another template command tag.

```
{% for item in form %}
    {% get_item {{ forloop.counter }} %}  --> How do I get this working?
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `{% get_item forloop.counter %}`